# MapMyFitness API authorization not using the correct callback

Tags: api, oauth, callback, authorize, mapmyfitness

I have been working with `MapMyFitness API`.  I had it working and the authorization ran smoothly.  Within the last two months it seems that something has either changed with my code or with their API.

During the request I make the following call:

```
header("Location: http://api.mapmyfitness.com/3.1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=123456789&oauth_callback=mysite.com/authorize.php);
```

It correctly sends me to the MapMyFitness site to grant access.  I enter in a valid username and password and then it redirects me to:

```
http://api.mapmyfitness.com/3.1/oauth/mysite.com/authorize.php?oauth_token=123456789
```

Of course the website and token are made up for this example.  If I remove the first part and am left with the actual callback, `mysite.com/authorize.php?oauth_token=123456789` it runs correctly.

It appears that MapMyFitness is not correctly handling my `callback` and adding its `oauth url`.

If I add `http://` to the callback I get the error:

```
Unknown request token ""Array ( [oauth_token] => 


f36a684c04ef71d0a129dd59f5bbc1ed0514b4598 [oauth_callback] => SITE [PHPSESSID] => 
p284bpatpiuu78t0105qal4ql4 [fbsr_44829295357] => om1lyMi6U5iIyXqI3nfoWSBW5IoNV8skkJ-
fvW5qec8.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUUFkSExOMkc0eWEtZk1NOF91WGtaNDhKMWN
DSmFQVnZEVm95RjZEdXRsNDVuYVRIUHNRdGxMRVhIQW9QSnJrNnhqWlZreTN6NzZCV1RTQWNaTXVTdl9HWEFNMDJkQ3p
1OE80dkhYT3lhUmdHVWl3bmdqcFF4SXYwQl9PUURNRlJzaG5wMDh2bjQ5UUI2S191ZHR5dXB5Z1dwbFNRdndqYTBiQ0h
IVExWN0ZialM5cnpjRGtnS0tVN2xyRVFXMVM2RTNkTzRQZHM1TnJjX0RrLVp3alEyRS0iLCJpc3N1ZWRfYXQiOjEzNjM
4ODQ3NTgsInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxMjcxODUyNTg0In0 [__utma] => 
252565653.331108727.1353966538.1363678118.1363880367.12 [__utmc] => 252565653 [__utmv] => 
252565653.|1=sex=M=1^2=age_group=35to44=1^3=membership=free=1^4=logged_in=is_logged_in=1 
[__utmz] => 252565653.1363678118.11.4.utmcsr=mapmyrun.com|utmccn=
(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/api/3.1/oauth/authorize 
[mp_d4aec1d8aa5a6d2aebd49ec451910dea_mixpanel] => {"distinct_id": "13d37eedea042c-0033ca7c4-
376f6050-1aeaa0-13d37eedea1e62","$initial_referrer": "$direct","$initial_referring_domain":
 "$direct","$search_engine": "google"} [optimizelyBuckets] => {} [optimizelySegments] => 
{"173102711":"safari","173022868":"false","172178767":"referral"} [__gads] => 
ID=2f74fc63a6725ad5:T=1362443034:S=ALNI_MblJOxnkm6q4rFDE8wihC_cUXHETQ [mmfsessid] => 
5a0f4259-05ae-4fe9-a45e-aa9f90afdfba [fbm_44829295357] => base_domain=.mapmyfitness.com 
[optimizelyEndUserId] => oeu1353966536109r0.12621341994963586 )
```

Comment: You're missing the protocol part in `oauth_callback=mysite.com/authorize.php`. It should be `oauth_callback=http://mysite.com/authorize.php` or `https`, whichever applies.

Comment: I've tried adding http:// and https:// and both ways cause an error and the 'grant access' page throws and error and does not load.

Comment: Unless you specify what error, no one is psychic here.

Comment: I added the error to the original post for using http://

Comment: If I don't use http:// I am allowed to go to the grant access page.  After entering a valid user/password.  I am given the following error:   Not Found

The requested URL /3.1/oauth/semlerHealthPerks.com/authorize.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add the full url for your callback in the initial call? i.e.

```
oauth_callback=http://mysite.com/authorize.php
```

Comment: It fails and does not even open the grant access page from MMF.  It gives the error: Unknown request token ""Array ( [oauth_token] => 123456789 [oauth_callback] => http://mysite.com/authorize.php ......

Comment: this is a dummy token, it's not the real one

Comment: I believe you are wrong.  As I stated in the post.  If I use mysite.com/authorize for the callback.  I make it to the 'grant access' page.  After entering a valid MMF user and password I am sent to a false address:  http://api.mapmyfitness.com/3.1/oauth/mysite.com/authorize.php?oauth_token=123456789.  If I remove api.mapmyfitness.com/3.1/oauth everything works correctly.  This is why I believe MMF is providing a false callback from the grant access page.

Answer (score 0):

Try urlencoding your `oauth_callback` value, e.g.:

```
http://api.mapmyfitness.com/3.1/oauth/authorize?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fauthorize.php...
```